# Submit form and redirect to another view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have 2 simple views: `home` and `create`. Here is the controller for them

```
public function index()
{
    $products = Product::all();
    return view('home', compact('products'));
}

public function createProduct() 
{
    return view('productCreate');
}
public function createProductSubmit( Request $request ) {


    $product = new Product;

    $product->productName = $request->name;
    $product->productPrice = $request->price;
    $product->quantity = strip_tags($request->quantity);
    $product->category_id = $request->category;

    $product->save();                              
    return view('home');
}
```

and the routes

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');

Route::get('/home/product/create', 'HomeController@createProduct');
Route::post('/home/product/create', 'HomeController@createProductSubmit');
```

The problem is that when I go in `/home/product/create` to create new product and after I add everything and submit the form I've get the error

> Undefined variable: products in home.blade.php

Why I get this error? In my `index()` function I have passing it?

Update

```
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>Product Name</th>
          <th>Product Price</th>
          <th>Product Quantity</th>
          <th>Category</th>
          <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
    @foreach( $products as $product )
        <tr>
          <th>{{ $product->id }}</th>
          <td>{{ $product->productName }}</td>
          <td>{{ $product->productPrice }}</td>
          <td>{{ $product->quantity }}</td>
          <td>{{ $product->category_id }}</td>
          <td><button class='btn btn-success'>Edit</button> <button class='btn btn-danger'>Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: show your home.blade.hp code and related controller code

Comment: @Md.SahadatHossain I've updated my question. Is just simple table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the following lines:

```
$product->save();                              
return view('home');
```

to

```
$product->save();                              
return redirect('/home');    // or what ever route you want
```

Comment: Thank's but now I get blank page and in the url i see `home/product/create`. Should be /home.. I don't get it what's happen

Comment: It's `return redirect('/home');`

Comment: Yes, @StuartWagner that make the trick. Thank's to both of you

Comment: Yes its return redirect('/home'); I forgot